# Using JavaScript to get data-attr and replace that attr with a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, click, attr

Ok so what I am trying to do is use javascript to get the attribute that I select, and use that as the javascript variable. Better if I show you anyways.

```
var a='<div id="element">Hello</div>';
var b="<span class="class">GoodBye</span>";
var c="<div id="element3">Filler Text</div>";
var d="<div id="element4">Filler text again</div>";
var e="<div id="element5">Filler text once more</div>";

$('.element').click(function(){
  var Element = $(this).attr('data-edit');
  $('#information_inner').html(Element);
  $('.pop_up').show();
 });
```

HTML markup would look like

```
<div class="element" data-edit="c"></div>
```

So we already know what is going to happen, the HTML will become c not the variable listed above. So how would you go about to retrieving the data-edit and changing it or making it to select as the javascript variable it list?

Comment: Double check that syntax highlighting, see that?

Comment: No I don't see anything...

Comment: You have to escape the double quotes or use single quotes, the string should be all red, see that now?

Comment: Opps I usually use single quotes as you can see from the first one. My bad. Just was writing fast to get my response. Thank you though. You can edit if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to probably move those variables into an object:

```
var text = {
    a: '<div id="element">Hello</div>',
    b: '<span class="class">GoodBye</span>',
    c: '<div id="element3">Filler Text</div>',
    d: '<div id="element4">Filler text again</div>',
    e: '<div id="element5">Filler text once more</div>'
}
```

Then you can use, e.g., `text['a']` to access one of these:

```
$('#information_inner').html( text[Element] );
```

Comment: Oh silly me :) I see I see. Thank you very much, as I never thought of this. I was wondering how in the world to do this. I appreciate this as all other answer on here are so simple and my question was more complex than those I've read.!!! Upvote and check!

Comment: I just used this and set two objects, one named title other named body. And it works awesomely! Thank you SO much I now understand the objects just a little bit more! you are awesome for helping!